# Levenshtein distance: addressing inconsistencies in spelling of string variables

Tags: r, string, levenshtein-distance

I am new to string manipulation, and I have a puzzle.
I have a very large dataset that looks something like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(id= c("abc name","abc names","abc name","other","very very long name","abc other id","bbc other id","other long name","two names"),x1 = rnorm(9), x2= rnorm(9))
> print(df)
#                   id          x1         x2              
# 1            abc name  0.38827655 -0.6855575
# 2           abc names -1.01248116 -0.4221539 
# 3            abc name  0.05076442 -0.7953287 
# 4               other -1.04510310 -0.4795451 
# 5 very very long name  1.27578095  0.3470104 
# 6        abc other id -0.22093223 -0.5508261 
# 7        bbc other id  0.47213061  0.4396293 
# 8     other long name  0.66464296 -0.2405145 
# 9           two names -0.17877376 -0.6957395
```

The issue with this data is that the id variable has some spelling mistakes. For example row 1,2 and 3 report data for the same ID, however, they are recorded with slightly different names ("abc name" vs "abc names").

I would like to create a new column (id_lev) that creates new id names cleaning spelling errors. This should be calculated using the Levenshtein distance (number of edits required to arrive to one name to the other as a proportion of the name length).

The final column should follow the following rules:

1. consider two names the same if their Levenshtein distance is <=0.5
2. replace the names of the less common spelling with the more common spelling (eg. row 2 should become "abc name" to match row 1 and 3).
3. if none of the ids is more popular, the first to appear should be preferred. Hence, in row 6 and 7 should become "abc other id".

The final dataset should look something like this:(of course the results of the id_lev will depend on whether the Levenshtein distance is <=0.5 rule.)

```
#                   id          x1         x2              id_lev
# 1            abc name  0.38827655 -0.6855575            abc name
# 2           abc names -1.01248116 -0.4221539            abc name
# 3            abc name  0.05076442 -0.7953287            abc name
# 4               other -1.04510310 -0.4795451               other
# 5 very very long name  1.27578095  0.3470104 very very long name
# 6        abc other id -0.22093223 -0.5508261        abc other id
# 7        bbc other id  0.47213061  0.4396293        abc other id
# 8     other long name  0.66464296 -0.2405145     other long name
# 9           two names -0.17877376 -0.6957395           two names
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Best regards

Comment: Why is there a 0.5 distance? Do you mean that editing costs differ across the types of edits (e.g. insertion = 0.5, deletion = 0.5, and substitution = 1)?

Comment: Sorry for not being too clear about this. I mean that the distance should be divided by the string length, (distance/length should be <=0.5) to ensure that for longer names allow larger strings.